# Programmatically render block content render array with wrappers

Tags: theming, entities, blocks

I'm trying to render a custom block, created through the UI, programmatically with a wrapper. I can do this:

```php
$block = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block_content')
  ->load($bid);

$output['header'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block_content')
  ->view($block);
```

And the block is rendered, but only the fields of the block - the block wrappers are not rendered.

I have tried adding:

```php
$output['header']['#theme_wrappers'][] = 'block';
```

This leads to errors:

> Warning: Undefined array key "#configuration" in [...]/block.module on line 200
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "#plugin_id" in [...]/block.module on line 212
>
> ...

So how can I programmatically render a `block_content` entity with block wrappers?

Comment: Not sure which wrappers you speak of. I don't see any difference in markup between placing a block and the code you have.

Comment: @NoSssweat - see the duplicate thread. That was the solution.

Comment: You could add a #theme_wrappers, the problem here, the core `block` template is not a suitable template for this.